# In Gremlin, after a Both() step, filter based on direction we just traversed

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I'd like to be able to do separate filters based on the direction of the traversal after a `Both()` step.
Here's a simplified query:

```
g.V("1").Both().Or(<direction was IN>, __.Has("tag", "some Value"))
```

I also considered doing separate `In()` and `Out()` steps, but I don't see a way to have the traverser branch in both directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be more clear to traverse `In()` and `Out()` separately. You can branch the traverser with `union()` and thus do:

```
g.V("1").Union(In().has("tag","some Value"),
               Out().has("tag","some Other Value"))
```

Comment: `Union()` is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!